# Preparing yeast for secondary fermentation

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters, secondary, barleywine

I have a barleywine in progress that seems to have stalled around 9% ABV with some residual sweetness I'd like to try and reduce.  After 2.5 weeks in primary all activity had stopped so I racked off to fresh fermentor.  Two more weeks with agitation and SG hasn't really fallen any more.

I'm thinking of pitching Safale US-05 to see if it can drop it a few more SG points.  I've found little advice on how to prepare yeast for such a toxic environment. [This comment in a post about preparing a starter](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showpost.php?p=3422665&postcount=3) argues it's a pointless exercise as only 'unhealthy' yeast will result from highly alcoholic environments.  Sounds a bit wonky to me - I'd expect unhealthy yeast to die and the survivors to be more resilient..

My own idea would be to rehydrate as usual in ~25°C water for ~15 mins, then slowly add barleywine over another 30 mins or so to gradually bring it up to 9% before pitching.  Seems more likely to give them a chance to adapt than by pitching straight from being rehydrated.

All views on this from those with relevant experience very much appreciated.

---

Edit: Details of (slightly experimental) recipe. Batch ~15L approx - all quantities are estimates as I used the parti-gyle split method..

Mash - 60 mins @ 67°C (target temps hit)

- 5.0 kg Marris Otter Pale
- 0.2 kg Crystal 120

Boil additions

- 0.1 kg roasted barley ('tea' from cold steep)
- 0.5 kg light DME

Nottingham yeast

OG 1.083 | FG 1.016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries...05 will perform fine without anything special.  Rehydrate it for best performance and then just toss it in.  I've gone to 12% ABV with it with no issues.  But my question is, how do you know it's the yeast?  Why isn't it a fermentability of wort issues?  Tell us more about your recipe and procedure in order to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Denny.  Recipe details added.  Any comments?

Comment: OK, I don't see a lot of unfermentables there in terms of ingredients.  The extract will be to some extent, but there's not a lot of that.  Nottingham should have no trouble at all dealing with a 1.083 beer.  However, since the gravity hasn't fallen further, I really suspect that fermentation is done.  I also think that's a fine FG for a 1.083 beer.  Is there some particular reason you want it lower or think it should be?

Comment: One thing you can do is try a fast ferment test (sometimes called a forced ferment test).  That will tell you is it's the wort or the yeast.  Take a sample and put it in a container like a jar.  Add a LOT of yeast to it...it can even be bread yeast.  All we want to do is find out how low that wort will ferment.  Leave it in a warm place for a few days, then take a reading again.  If it's dropped, you know there's still fermentation to be done.  If it hasn't, the beer is finished.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah maybe it is done.  It is still a bit sweet though, although perhaps that'll reduce after 3 months conditioning.  I've pitched the 05 anyway to see if there's any effect.

Comment: Keep in mind that sweetness can be as much due to lack of hops as fermentation.  Also, alcohol adds sweetness, so stronger beers will seem sweeter.